# add Java classes to classpath.txt, no root user

Tags: matlab

Hello I am trying to add some Java classes to the Matlab `classpath.txt`.

But when I do `edit([matlabroot '\toolbox\local\classpath.txt'])` I can open a read only file because I do not have root permissions from writing `/usr/local/matlab`.

Is there a way to do it without root permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it taking into account these two facts:

- By default, Matlab probably has your user folder as part of the [path](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/path.html) (check typing `path` in the command window).
- Matlab executes the file `matlabrc.m` on startup. That script, among other things, looks for another script called `startup.m` and, if it exists, executes it (see [`matlabrc` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/matlabrc.html)).

So: create a file called `startup.m` (if it doesn't already exist) in your user folder, and that file will get executed on startup. You can do the adding of Java classes there.

Comment: Note that you can determine your user folder with the `userpath` command. For example, you could open `startup.m` in the editor with the following command, `edit(fullfile(regexp(userpath,'^[^;]*','match','once'),'startup.m'))`.